# angular.js:12408 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error on ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code:

```
<input ng-required="{{ ixarisCurrOpts[0].selected }}" 
      ng-pattern="[0R]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{23}" ng-click="returnFundAccGBP()" 
      ng-focus="fFundAccGBP=true" 
      ng-change="returnFundAccGBP()" ng-blur="fFundAccGBP=false" 
      ng-model="fundAccGBP" id="fundAccGBP" name="fundAccGBP" type="text" 
      placeholder="{{ fundAccRegexPrefix }}ACO_EpAn03f8X-DyWAc0n3L"
      class="form-control input-md" maxlength="25" ng-class="fFundAccGBPDef">
```

I keep getting this error in the google chrome debugger:

Error:

> [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'R' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 3 of the expression [[0R]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{23}] starting at [R]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{23}].

Comment: change your regex to: /^[0R]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{23}/

Answer (score 0):

Your `ng-pattern` syntax is incorrect. It has to be inside fwd. slash  `/.../`.

Change it to `ng-pattern="/^[0R]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{23}$/"`. It will work.

pattern regex updated too.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what's already been said: you should use "^" and "$" in the beginning and the end of the pattern, respectively:

```
"/^[0R]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{23}$^/"
```

This way, you assert that the pattern starts working from the beginning to the very end of the string.